# Variable string formatting in python 3

Tags: string, python-3.x, string-formatting

Input is a number, e.g. 9 and I want to print decimal, octal, hex and binary value from 1 to 9 like:

```
1     1     1     1
2     2     2    10
3     3     3    11
4     4     4   100
5     5     5   101
6     6     6   110
7     7     7   111
8    10     8  1000
9    11     9  1001
```

How can I achieve this in python3 using syntax like

```
dm, oc, hx, bn = len(str(9)), len(bin(9)[2:]), ...
print("{:dm%d} {:oc%s}" % (i, oct(i[2:]))
```

I mean if number is 999 so I want decimal 10 to be printed like ' 10' and binary equivalent of 999 is 1111100111 so I want 10 like '      1010'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and its [mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) to do the whole thing for you:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    print("{v} {v:>6o} {v:>6x} {v:>6b}".format(v=i))
```

Which will print:

```
1      1      1      1
2      2      2     10
3      3      3     11
4      4      4    100
5      5      5    101
6      6      6    110
7      7      7    111
8     10      8   1000
9     11      9   1001
```

**UPDATE**: To define field 'widths' in a variable you can use a format-within-format structure:

```
w = 5  # field width, i.e. offset to the right for all octal/hex/binary values

for i in range(1, 10):
    print("{v} {v:>{w}o} {v:>{w}x} {v:>{w}b}".format(v=i, w=w))
```

Or define a different width variable for each field *type* if you want them non-uniformly spaced.

Btw. since you've tagged your question with [`python-3.x`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x), if you're using Python 3.6 or newer, you can use [`Literal String Interpolation`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to simplify it even more:

```
w = 5  # field width, i.e. offset to the right for all octal/hex/binary values

for v in range(1, 10):
    print(f"{v} {v:>{w}o} {v:>{w}x} {v:>{w}b}")
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I use a previously assigned variable instead of 6 in {v:>6o} ?

Comment: @NishantIngle - Yes you can. Check the update above.